# If Textbox is empty set datetime field to NULL in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to set a datetime field in a SQL table to NULL if the textbox is empty, I can't seem to get this to work.

```
        string EndDate = "";
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EndDateTxtBox.Text.Trim()))
        {
            EndDate = null;
        }
        else
        {
            EndDate = EndDateTxtBox.Text;
        }

        var sql = String.Format(@"UPDATE Test SET StartDate='{0}', 
                                 EndDate='{1}' WHERE ID = '{2}'",
                                 StartDateTxtBox.Text, EndDate, id);
```

When I do this and put in a break point I get this for "var sql':

```
"UPDATE Test SET StartDate='5/23/2013', EndDate=" WHERE ID = '19'"
```

I tried removing the ' from the sql string but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Edit: I understand the importance of preventing against SQL injection but this a page on my internal web server for my use only and not projected to the public. It's to help me keep track of personal things.

Comment: Let's say it together: ***do not concatenate user-input into SQL***

Comment: OP, a tip, look at the formatting of that SQL in your post. Either you messed up copying it into the post or it's a little hint your SQL statement is badly wrong.

Comment: @MarcGravell, why do you always have to be the voice of reason? :D

Comment: @kcray, what formats are the columns that the `StartDate` and `EndDate` are stored in? Please don't tell me `VARCHAR`....

Comment: This has been a huge learning experience, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parameterize.

First, you should move the UI code away from the database code, so that by the time it gets anywhere near the DB we have correctly typed data. For example:

```
void UpdateDates(int id, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate) {...}
```

and put whatever `Parse` etc code you want **at the caller** - not near the db. Now we need to implement that:

```
void UpdateDates(int id, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate) {
    //... where-ever cmd comes from, etc
    cmd.CommandText =
        "update Test set StartDate=@start, EndDate=@end where ID = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", startDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", (object)endDate ?? DBNull.Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // ... cleanup etc
}
```

Or with a tool like "dapper":

```
void UpdateDates(int id, DateTime startDate, EndDate? endDate) {
    //... where-ever connection comes from, etc
    connection.Execute(
        "update Test set StartDate=@start, EndDate=@end where ID = @id",
        new { id, start = startDate, end = endDate}); // painfully easy
    // ... cleanup etc
}
```

Comment: +1: and of course you have to provide an even more robust solution! You make me proud!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is the single quotes. If it is NULL then you shouldn't have them.

Also, you probably want to be using a parameterized query (for safety reasons and pass in the values). In that case the quotes shouldn't be necessary either.

Comment: I didn't see Michael Perrenoud's reply when I posted mine but his answer is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the `string.format line`. you cannot include a line break in the string portion.  Try one of the following.

```
 var sql = String.Format(
          @"UPDATE Test SET StartDate='{0}', EndDate='{1}' WHERE ID = '{2}'",
           StartDateTxtBox.Text, EndDate, id);
```

or,

```
    var sql = String.Format(@"UPDATE Test SET StartDate='{0}', " + 
                             "EndDate='{1}' WHERE ID = '{2}'",
                             StartDateTxtBox.Text, EndDate, id);
```

but, as other answers here mention, you should learn about SQL injection and consider another approach.

Comment: Please don't encourage further SQL injection possibilities.

Comment: @Michael,  Yes, Sql injection IS important. and the op should, as soon as possible, learn about it, and how to code against it.  But I try to tailor my answers here to the op's level of expertise, at least as far as is discernible from their question.  It's a steep learning curve from noobie to professionally handling security issues.  And how do we know what this app does, where it runs, what the consequences of  security vulnerabilities are, etc.?

Comment: Just an FYI, if it even matters, this is a site running on an internal network for my use only. I guess I should of stated that. No one will have access to it but me.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, I fully understand your position, and I didn't downvote your answer, but my position is this. You practice how you play. If you write a local app that's only for your use but allow for SQL Injection, then that's how you'll code your other apps. **Further, am I not my brother's keeper?** Is it not more appropriate for me to lead my brother down a better path, or should I let him get hit by the car? So, as I stated, pedantic isn't the right word here.

Comment: @Michael,  Hah! I guess I disagree with you.  Unless he/she asks me, I am not my brother's keeper!  But, again, seriously, if you're learning how to tie your shoelaces it is not helpful to have some PETA nut lecturing you about how using leather shoes is a moral crime against animals.  And don't say that is an absurd example, it is just further out on the same spectrum.

Comment: We're not talking about tying shoelaces here. We're talking about someone pointing a loaded shotgun and aiming at his feet. You don't then tell that person how to pull the trigger. But nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the issues in your code that are not regarded as SQL best practices within C# code, you have several issues:

1. You're setting EndDate to a C# null. That is not the same as an SQL NULL, which is denoted as DBNull.Value
2. You have no regard for the fact that NULL doesn't need quotes in SQL, so your SQL would need to be different anyway in order to work even if you fix #1.

I suggest to write a Stored Procedure; if the end date textbox is null, just don't pass that parameter, and make it have a default value of NULL in the stored proc.

```
Create Procedure usp_TestDateRange_Update
( @ID int -- or whatever type your ID is
  @StartDate DateTime,
  @EndDate DateTime = NULL)
As 
  Update Test
  Set StartDate = @StartDate,
      EndDate = @EndDate
  Where ID = @ID
```

Something like that. Now what you need to do is make your C# code call the stored procedure and add the parameters to the call from your textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
string sql = String.Format(@"UPDATE Test SET StartDate={0}, 
                                     EndDate={1} WHERE ID = {2}",
                     (StartDateTxtBox.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty) ? StartDateTxtBox.Text:"NULL"), EndDate, id);
```